# django logout from admin without clearing all session

Tags: python, django, session, admin, logout

I have a `User` model

```
class User(models.Model):
    ....
```

I created a `LoginMiddleware` that will add a boolean variable containing wether there is a user logged in or not

```
class LoginMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        request.current_user = self.get_user(request)
        request.is_user_logged = request.current_user != None
            
    def get_user(self, request):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e)) # gives key error because admin logout clears all session variables
            return None
```

This is how I use it :

```
def account(request):
    if not request.is_user_logged:
        return redirect('/login/')
```

I realized that when I logout from admin my current user is also logged out, as the default behaviour clears all the session variables, including `user_id` which is set during login

```
KeyError at /account/
'user_id'
```

Comment: The current logged in user is the admin user... It's only logical that once you log out from admin you log out from the website as well. If you want to continue on to the website simply don't logout and continue browsing. Also no need for a middleware to add a boolean variable simply `request.user.is_authenticated` would be enough.

Comment: is there any workaround ? it might not be suitable for multi tenants websites where each client has its own domain. they can be logged in on both user and admin area at the same time.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I'm using a custom `User` model, notice `request.current_user` instead of `request.user`

Comment: `request.user` will have your custom user model properly as long as you set [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in your settings properly. Multi tenant sites normally have separate domains or sub-domains to separate users. If you keep your admin site on a different domain / subdomain you will not have this issue of logging out of multiple places. See [django-hosts](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it is a package which allows you to easily use multiple subdomains.